# how to implement $size in spring Data Aggregation in java

Tags: java, mongodb

how to implement below code in java using spring Data mongodb

```
db.profil.aggregate([
   { "$match": { "typ": "Organisation" } },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": null,
        "count": {
            "$sum": { "$size": "$foos" }
        }
    } }
])
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has an [Aggregation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/builders/aggregation/) framework for Java to support all aggregation APIs.

Try following:

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.*;

Bson match = match(eq("typ", "Organisation")));
Bson projection = new Document("$size", "$foos" );
Bson group = group("$_id", Accumulators.sum("count",projection));
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.aggregate(asList(match, group)).iterator();
```